# Position an html element at any x/y coordinate in a page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given X and Y coordinates, I want to  position an element so it's in that position on screen/window.

I want scroll to work as normal, so position fixed isn't a solution. I want what fixed does but the element should move like a normal element when scrolling.

There are no guarantees what the parent html element position will be anything. That is it can be static, relative, absolute or fixed).

I understand css only solution is not possible and that's OK.

Comment: Add a fiddle which explains the code you have tried

Comment: Fiddle is always a good option to show your work that you have tried till now. I will recommend you this.  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: So your looking to have the position absolute element using the current scroll x/y position as well.. That should more or less just be a case of its base position and then having something like a class that fires on a window scroll event that will adjust the base x/y with the scroll offset

Comment: +10k views.. but no solutions?

Answer (score 6):

The equivalent of fixed positioning but with scroll is `position: absolute`.  It is relative to the parent position, as long as that doesn't have static positioning.

In the CSS:

```
#yourElement {
    position: absolute;
}
```

And in JavaScript with `x` and `y` values:

```
var element = document.getElementById("yourElement");
element.style.left = x + "px";
element.style.top = y + "px";
```

Comment: I mentioned in the question that the parent can be any position type.

Comment: Unfortunately, static-positioned elements result in absolutely positioned children using the bounds of the nearest ancestor node that isn't static.  It is possible to whip something up that takes this into account, but that's really not necessary.

I would advise simply setting the parent element's positioning to relative with no offsets in any direction if this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

Since this one is still open, got bored with JS Fiddle... Not sure if i meet the requirements of what you wanted?

http://jsfiddle.net/9Lz58n3o/

Example Page

```
<div> 
    using this div as an example of large text / body contents... can be ignored        
</div>
<div class="myStaticPos" tmpleft="32" tmptop="32" style="left:32px; top:32px;"></div>
<div class="myStaticPos" tmpleft="123" tmptop="123" style="left:123px; top:123px;"></div>
```

CSS

```
.myStaticPos {
    position:absolute; 
    background-color:#d00; 
    width:32px; 
    height:32px;
}
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
      alignElements();
  });
});

function alignElements() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
     $( ".myStaticPos" ).each(function() {
         $(this).offset({ top: scrollTop + parseInt($(this).attr("tmptop")), left: parseInt($(this).attr("tmpleft")) });       
    });    
}
```

This above example and in the fiddle link is one way of using a elements offset to have it always appear regardless of scrolling.. Otherwise a position absolute is a position absolute..

If this does not suite your needs or cant be adjusted, then please verify the question a little more.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this. However, you made absolute position work as fixed position. I want something similar but different. I want to position to work like fixed (i.e. relative to the 0,0 / window / body) but participate in scrolling . i.e. when I scroll the page the element should scroll - absolute position relative to the top left corner of a page.

Comment: This would just be relative of the page page.?

Comment: Maybe you haven't helped OP, but you sure helped me with this, thank you!