# Showing text inside shape, on a specific location

Tags: css, angular, svg, hebrew, shape-outside

I’m trying to implement an app that will combine a text, and an audio of the text being read, with “read-along” functionality: the line of text being read is highlighted. Also, clicking on a specific line, jumps to that position in the audio. I have a program in Angular that can do the “read-along” (each sentence being an object, with info about its position in the audio, displayed as individual ’s one after the other).

Here’s some code.

```
<p>
  <span *ngFor="let sentence of sentences"
    [id]="sentence.line"
    [ngClass]="{'active': sentence.active}"
    [ngClass]="{'inactive': !sentence.active}"
    [ngStyle]="(currentTime >= sentence.start_time && currentTime < sentence.end_time)
                 ? playingStyle
                 : (hoveredID === sentence.line)
                     ? hoveredStyle
                     : normalStyle"
    (mouseover) = "showHovered(sentence.line)"
    (mouseout) = "showNormal()"
    (click)="sentence.active && play(sentence.start_time)"
    [innerHTML]="sentence.text"
    >
  </span>
</p>
```

The difficulty I’m having is that **the text is to be displayed in a specific position and shape**, on top of a background picture, so that it resembles the original book. The text is in Hebrew and needs to be displayed as RTL. (See for example [CircularFLO](https://www.circularflo.com/), but I don't have a Mac, or InDesign, and I had trouble using it to display Hebrew RTL)

It seems that the CSS **shape-inside** has not been implemented, and it needs to be mimicked using shape-outside… I don’t find this practical for my needs.

I have looked at the following, among others:

- https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/#toc-inside-shape
- https://css-tricks.com/using-css-to-set-text-inside-a-circle/
- https://codepen.io/noahblon/pen/pjvPPN

So: Is there any other option I could look into? I’m willing to try other technologies, and am not limited and stuck to creating a web application. But I do want it to be available to people without a Mac (including myself as the programmer).

Would SVG `<tspan>` be the way to go?

Thanks!

Comment: can you please provide stackblitz example ?

Comment: I deleted the link to stackblitz that I hade provided on Dec 28, because it didn't lead to an answer, and because I think the code is not so crucial for answering the question. Anyway in the meantime I think I found that SVG will not help me because there's no text wrapping. I'm looking into the answer by "Angry 84" at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28598910/position-an-html-element-at-any-x-y-coordinate-in-a-page

Comment: I'm confused about your RTL problem ... `direction:rtl` fixes that for me. I cannot find shape-inside on https://caniuse.com/?search=shape- either. And please add a screenshot or 2 to show what you need. I myself have a scroll to word without a background image.

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply sooner, but this is just my _no paying_ hobby. I found that SVG is not the way to go, as it doesn't do line wrapping. I just divided my shape (that the text needs to be inside of) into two rectangular blocks. They are positioned to form the correct shape. Even though half of a sentence may be at the end of one block, and the other half at the beginning of the next one, they behave as one sentence for highlighting and clicking purposes since they share the same `[id]="sentence.line"`
I'm sorry I can't show screenshots as the program is not currently working :-(